# Как определяется память для массива?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, структуры

Сколько выделяется памяти для статического массива? Допустим у меня есть массив и его фиксированная длина 10. Я только определил

```
string [] xy = new string [9];
LinkedList<String> xz = new LinkedList(){{xz.add *10}};
```

Получается, у меня есть массив с 10 элементами и список с 10 элементами. Тип и т.д. всё одно и тоже, даже вставляемые в них данные.
Сколько памяти выделится массиву и как ведется подсчет и сколько списку?

Comment: new string [9] - массив из 9 элементов (не 10)

Comment: @благодарю за внимательность.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/java-how-much-memory-do https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml